# Danger, jeopardy, hazard. What's the difference?

Tags: difference

I've looked through a number of discussions on the internet about this question, but still don't get it. Looks like they are almost total synonyms. But I'm confused by the fact that "jeopardy" and "hazard" are used very rarely.

Are they even used in everyday life? Is it ok to say something like this?

> Your career is in jeopardy

Comment: What discussions.  I doubt we can add more that you've already seen or read in dictionaries.  They aren't perfect synonyms.  Jeopardy is somewhat rare, but hazard is quite common. all three are used in everyday life]

Comment: If you can't find the difference in a dictionary then it is useful to study the origins of English words. I suggest you look each one up in an etymology dictionary  Here's an example https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=danger -   I also suggest you study usage. You can find quotations on Google ngGram and Google Books.  Example https://www.google.com/search?q=%22danger%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1972,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en

Answer (score 1):

I think that they are different because they are used in different ways. For example, I'll use the sentence that you gave in the question: Your career is in jeopardy. This works, as well as in danger, but it doesn't work with hazard; 'your career is in hazard' is just not something that is correct idiomatically or is said at all. Also, the words 'hazard' and 'jeopardy' are not synonyms, as a fire hazard for instance *is not* a fire jeopardy. Yes, hazard and jeopardy are used in everyday life, and it is okay for you to say that your career is in jeopardy. But hazard, danger, and jeopardy are *not* 'almost total synonyms', so I think that before you research this more, you should see whether or not your 'a number of discussions on the internet' are reputable sources or not.